# how to access 2 keys in a hashmap in same loop?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to access `key1` and `key2` in same for loop using `Map.Entry`. But at a time `entry.getKey()` returns the current key only. How do I access 2 keys at same time?

```java
for(Map.Entry<Long, NodeDisjoint1> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    long parent1 = findSet(entry.getKey());
    long parent2 = findSet(entry.getKey());
}
```

Comment: You can't. Which one would be the second key? You'd have to go with regular loop most likely.

Comment: the next key in the hashmap is the second key? Any alternative method is even appreciable.

Comment: do you know the keys in advance?

Comment: And depending on the map, your order will psuedorandomly change. What are you actually trying to accomplish here? Edit: HashMap is one such map

Comment: The " for( : )" won't work because the object (here map) is bound. BUT: it may work if you change it to the classic way "for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); ++i)" and use the map.get(i).

Comment: Yes. All the keys are there in the hashmap.

Comment: So why do you need to iterate on the keys? Usually, if you know the key, you just get the entry, as in `map.get(1)`

Comment: I think Federico was asking if you had a predictable pattern to the keys, so as to iterate meaningfully.

Answer (score 1):

Do it as follows:

```
Set<Map.Entry<Long, NodeDisjoint1>> entrySet = map.entrySet();
List<Map.Entry<Long, NodeDisjoint1>> entryList = new ArrayList<>(entrySet);
ListIterator<Map.Entry<Long, NodeDisjoint1>> itr = entryList.listIterator();
long parent1, parent2;
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    parent1 = findSet((Entry)itr.next().getKey());
    if(itr.hasNext()) {
        parent2 = findSet((Entry)itr.next().getKey());
        itr.previous();
    }
}
```

## Demo:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30, 40));
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(set);
        ListIterator<Integer> itr = list.listIterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
            if (itr.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(itr.next());
                itr.previous();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
10
20
20
30
30
40
40
```

Feel free in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: How will you get a pair of 2nd and 3rd keys with this implementation?

Comment: @Amongalen - I didn't understand your question. Please elaborate with some example.

Comment: In a single iteration of your loop you move the iterator by two elements. In the first iteration `parent1 == value for 1st key && parent2 == value for 2nd key`. In the next iteration `parent1 == value for 3rd key && parent2 == value for 4th key`. And so on. Your code won't produce a case where `parent1 == value for 2nd key && parent2 == value for 3rd key`. In OPs example tho it would produce that result.

Comment: Yes, I am actaully implementing a disjoint set data structure and trying to detect a cycle in it. If all the nodes like 1,2 then 2,3 then 3,4 are not accessed then output will be wrong.

Comment: @EshuManohare - I've updated my answer based on your clarification. I hope it works for you. Feel free in case of any doubt/issue.

Answer (score 0):

With ***1 ENTRYSET*** you ***CAN ACCESS ONLY TO 1 KEY AND 1 VALUE***